# Steam Game Removal on Different Drives

Tags: steam

If I am trying to uninstall Steam and it is in my C: drive while some of my other games are installed onto my F: drive, will it remove those games on the F: and C: drive or just on the C: drive?

Answer (score 1):

Uninstalling Steam will also remove all of your installed games (including in separate libraries), save games, and other downloadable content.

If you want to back up your games before uninstalling Steam, say for example you're reinstalling the client, you can take a copy of your library folder before you perform the uninstallation and then restore it after uninstalling the client. When you reinstall Steam you need to create a new library at the existing library location and then choose to reinstall all of the games in that library for Steam to correctly find the files.

Comment: I wasn't aware that this was the case, but assuming you're correct, you can also unlink a secondary library folder, which should prevent Steam from uninstalling any games located in that library.

Comment: Is this new behavior? Used Steam on Win, Mac, and Linux and could always uninstall it with games in a Steam Library Folder outside the client without problems. It has been a few years though.

Comment: It's what it says on the [Steam help pages](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=9609-OBMP-2526) "This process will remove Steam and any installed game content from your machine. If reinstalling Steam and Steam games in the near future, please move the Steamapps folder (C:\Program Files\Steam\Steamapps) outside of the Steam directory to prevent your games from being deleted. "

Comment: @kalina that warning only applies to the Steamapps folder inside the Steam directory (C:\Program Files\Steam), and not to any secondary folders outside the Steam directory.